# Can not start vMX in EVE-NG

Tags: emulator, emulation

I upload the vmx-14.1 directory(contains `hda.qcow2` image) to EVE-NG's vm `/opt/unetlab/addons/qemu` path.

but when I use it, I can not start ip up.

> [image]

---

**EDIT-01**

My EVE-NG memory size is 6 GB.

Comment: You give your eve-ng how much memory?

Comment: hi, see my edit-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Juniper vMX takes a lot of memory, you should give your EVE-NG more than 16GB, then you can start the vMX.

I experienced this problem. I can not start the Juniper images by my PC.

Answer (score 0):

It could be able to start this vMX version in a tiny PC with 8GB RAM. Actually, I run it in a iMac core i5 8GB RAM and VMware fusion. My EVE VMware image was allocated 4GB RAM and the vMX image with 6 interfaces was allocated 4 CPU and 2GB RAM. At the beginning, I cannot start vMX. After workaround, I found that vMX can start if I have more than 20GB free disk space within EVE image.

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking its **Nested Virtualization** problem if you are using Eve-Ng top of the Exsi.

You can enable VHV on a per VM basis and using the vSphere Client adds the **vhv.enable = "true"** parameter to the Eve-ng VM's .VMX configuration file.

I was faced same problem and solved by adding **vhv.enable = "true"** on .VMX file.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.eve-ng.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/EVE-Comm-BOOK-1.09-2020.pdf Page33: Step 6: IMPORTANT Open VM Settings. Set the quantity of CPUs and number of cores per socket. Set Intel VT-x/EPT. Hardware Virtualization engine to ON (checked). Once I checked this field, all nodes are started to work.

copied from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261810/eve-ng-qemu-based-nodes-are-not-starting/65677636#65677636